# How to get fstream to save to any windows desktop that opens the .exe in c++

Tags: c++, fstream

I'm making a program for my brother that will display 50,000 proxie variations and will save them all to a .txt.

How can I make it so any windows machine that uses this code will get the .txt to save to the desktop.

Here's what I have:

```
fstream file;
    file.open("proxies.txt", ios::out);
    string line;

    streambuf* stream_buffer_cout = cout.rdbuf();
    streambuf* stream_buffer_cin = cin.rdbuf();

    streambuf* stream_buffer_file = file.rdbuf();

    cout.rdbuf(stream_buffer_file);

    
    for (int i = 1; i < 50001; i++)
    {
        cout << n1 << i << n2 << "\n";
    }

    file.close();
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get what you are asking you just need to replace "proxies.txt" with an absolute path to a file in the desktop folder. You can get the desktop directory with the Win32 call `SHGetFolderPath` and put the path together using the standard (C++17) file system calls if you want, as below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <fstream>
#include <shlobj_core.h>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

std::string desktop_directory() {
    char path[MAX_PATH + 1];
    if (SHGetFolderPathA(HWND_DESKTOP, CSIDL_DESKTOP, NULL, 
            SHGFP_TYPE_DEFAULT, path) == S_OK) {
        return path;
    } else {
        return {}; // I'm not sure why this would fail...
    }
}

int main() {

    std::fstream file;
    auto desktop_path = fs::path(desktop_directory()) / "proxies.txt";
    file.open(desktop_path, std::ios::out);

    // ...

    file.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `SHGetSpecialFolderPath()` has been deprecated for a very long time. Use `SHGetFolderPath()` instead. Or, on Vista+, you can use `SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Desktop)` instead

Comment: i changed the answer to use SHGetFolderPath